# Parse a String date like this: March 03/12/2016 to just 03/12/2016

Tags: c#, parsing, datetime

I need to do a simple parse the strip out the actual word March (or whatever month it is) from a data saved to a string like this: "March 03/12/2016".

The ending results need to be a string such as: "03/12/2016".

I have been looking through date time formatters and I am not finding a simple method to strip out a month.  I was thinking of just cutting the string down to count 11 characters from right to left and then just trimming out the rest but I feel like that is sloppy and there is probably a date format option out there that I'm just not finding.

Any Suggestions?

Comment: regex it out `\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}'`

Comment: @rory I'm a science person I'm lucky I can spell or write a proper sentence.  I would like to also point that this is not relevant to my question, but thank you for the heads up.

Comment: @rory I do appreciate it as I certainly have used that wrong for many many years.  I just looked up the use cases of the word.  Face Palm.

Comment: You're welcome, from one New Englander to another :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another approach:

```
string result = input.Split(' ')[1];
```

Answer (score 4):

Just do this:

```
string input = "March 03/12/2016";
string output = input.Substring(input.IndexOf(' ') + 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that month name is proper English name for the month, you can use `MMMM` to extract month name. Then, you can just format the date however you wish.

```
var date = "March 03/12/2016";
var parsedDate = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "MMMM MM/dd/yyyy", new CultureInfo("en-US"));
Console.WriteLine(parsedDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"));
```

See in [dotnetfiddle.net](https://dotnetfiddle.net/zkNLmZ).

Bear in mind that if months parsed from the date will be different, eg. `October 03/12/2016`, exception will be thrown.

Answer (score 1):

```
string input = "March 03/12/2016";
string output;
int index = input.IndexOf(' ');

if(index >= 0) //Checks if there exists a space
{
    output = input.Substring(input.IndexOf(' ') + 1);
}
```

You need to first check if there will always be a space, because if it does not exist it will present problems since `input.IndexOf` does not have error handling.